# Postgresql: update command not stopping

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a postgresql 9.2 installation with a table that contains customer data (~ 500K customers), including unfortunately also some heavy `bytea` type fields.

```
CUSTOMERS1 |    id    |   first name  |  last name  |   ...
-----------------------------------------------------   ...
               c1005         ...            ...         ...
```

We have the task to merge the data with an external source, that unfortunately is not using exactly the same foreign key.

```
CUSTOMERS2 |    id    |   first name  |  last name  |   ...
-----------------------------------------------------   ...
              101005         ...            ...         ...
```

So while `customers1` has the id `c1005` in `customers2` the same id is `101005`, i.e. the `c` is just dropped and `100000` is added to the id.

I'm now trying to add a column `customers2_id` to `customers1` that contains the same id as it is in `customers2`. I have come up with the following SQL command:

```
ALTER TABLE customers1 ADD COLUMN customers2_id numeric(15,0);
UPDATE customers1 
SET customers2_id = to_number(trim(leading 'c' from id), '9999') + 100000;
```

Unfortunately when I run the command it takes forever (we let it run for >15 hours and still not finished). In addition, the postgres processes seem to be idle (according to activity monitor).

Some notes:

- we have removed the indices
- running the `UPDATE` command with e.g. `WHERE id = 'c1005'` runs fast up to having ~10 elements in the WHERE clause, with 20 elements speed degrades massively
- this experiment showed that this operation can be performed fast: we just did a `INSERT INTO` a new table and specified as values inserted the select statement `SELECT id, to_number(trim(leading 'c' from id), '9999') + 100000 FROM customers2`; it run in <10 seconds
- we have the impression that the bytea fields are the main problem

How could we speed up things and solve this problem? What could be the true problem that it is that slow?

Comment: Most likely the `ALTER TABLE` is blocked by some operations on this table.

Comment: @IgorRomanchenko: Sounds suspicious: a deadlock would eventually cause the query to error out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the table was corrupt. We copied the table by re-creating the schema and doing an `INSERT INTO` (for convenience we added the new id field to the new schema and let it calculate the new id at insertion time). Now everything works smoothly.

Comment: Corrupted table? Sounds really odd. Have never heard about Postgres corrupting tables. (Except for cases of disc or file system failures)